# Lines appear on mesh after adding shrinkwrap modifier

Tags: modifiers, topology, shrinkwrap

I'm shrinkwrapping mesh onto the target mesh, but I can see slight lines appearing. I have already added the subsurfaces modifier, which I think caused this issue. Is there any way to fix this?
The mesh Plane.001 has triple the geometry of the mesh plane.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you figured out the issue? I'm currently struggling with the same thing.

Comment: Try this method, it should help you organise your mesh to avoid pinching, hope it helps.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3rlMzsBWtPY&t=244s